# How to remove value from an element according to a condition in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, hide, element

I'm trying to remove the `values`, and `hide` the `elements`, by changing a `select`. I know how to hide, but I would like a remove the `values` if something has been written.

Here's my code :

```
<select v-model="switchopera">
  <option :value="undefined" selected disabled
    >Is the reservation under the same name ?</option>
  <option :value="false"
    >Yes</option>
  <option :value="true"
    >No</option>
</select>

<select
  :required="switchopera ? false : true"
  :value="switchopera ? false : true">
  <option selected disabled>Title (on the reservation)</option>
  <option>Mr</option>
    <option>Mrs/option>
</select>
```

And here's my Vuejs code :

```
  data() {
    return {
      switchopera: undefined
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using a computed property?

Comment: What elements do you want to hide, what values do you want to remove? Be more specific.

Comment: I wanted to delete the value of the second select, when the switchopera is false.Thing is, in my problem, it doesn't remove the value it just changes it to [object], [object].

Answer (score 0):

you can use watch property to check and do actions :

```
watch: {
switchopera: function(value){
  // do action
}
}
```

Comment: I wanted to delete the value of the second select, when the switchopera is false.Thing is, in my problem, it doesn't remove the value it just changes it to [object], [object].